# Deleting or removing ManagedObject in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

In the documentation and in the broad literature the generated factory method to delete/remove a subclassed managed object in CoreData for IOS is

```
(void)removeXXXObject:(NSManagedObject *)value
```

where XXX is the corresponding relationship or we can use simply removeObject.

In my code I used this:

```
Data *lastData = [[self sortedPersonDatas] objectAtIndex:0];
[selectedPerson removePersonDatasObject:lastData];
```

where PersonDatas is a one-to-many relationship to Data managed object from I took the last data (lastData resulted from a sorted array of all data)
But using the first two remove methods and checking the SQL database behind we can find that the actual data is existing just the inverse relationship is null.
To completely delete the data (all attributes and the object) I had to use:

```
[selectedPerson.managedObjectContext deleteObject:lastData];
```

The question: which is the better method and is it correct that CoreData leaves the data intact?

Comment: Do you save context after your delete operation?

Comment: Yes I saved the context, it's not the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`removeXXXObject` only removes an object from a to-many relationship, but does not delete the object from the store. To do so, you have to indeed use `deleteObject` - this is the desired behavior. Calling `deleteObject` will by default also set the corresponding relationships to nil (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW1).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I am not absolutely convinced that this behavior is correct. Based on the docs which you have cited too, if you switch the relationship (here: personDatas) rule from nullify to cascade it has to delete the object, as in the Apple docs: "Delete the objects at the destination of the relationship." But as I  tried it the "removeXXXObject" with cascade rule do not delete the object just nullify the relationship which is disturbing as the nullify rule does the same. Strange.

Comment: @BootMaker: "Delete Rule: Cascade" means: If a "Person" object is deleted, then all related "Data" objects are also deleted. It does not mean: If a "Data" object is removed from the related "Person", then it is deleted. - So the "Delete Rule" specifies: "What happens if this object is deleted?"

Comment: @Martin R: What you said is what I thought about cascade rule earlier, but what the the Apple docs says is different, the destination object of the relationship is the Data. Your Q: Don't know the answer as this is not the issue, but I will try it just for fun.

Comment: @BootMaker: The Apple docs say: "A relationship's delete rule specifies what should happen if an attempt is made to delete the source object." - So they apply only if an object is deleted, not if an object is removed from a relationship.

Comment: @Martin R: Thanks, that's correct. But the original question is different.

Comment: Even I think that the App docs don't really differentiate clearly the remove and delete methods I accept MrMage answer.